How can I use the Where-Object in PSCommand in c#?
I am creating multiple conditional statements that look at the different PowerShell Commands. One I am having issue is get-hotfix where I want to use where-object but I am gettig this error when I invoke the PSCommand

System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: 'Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "$_.InstalledOn -gt $StartTimeGenerated" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".'

Here is my code:
if(command == "get-hotfix")
{
    _HotFixViewAll = ReadInfo("ViewAllHotFix");
    _hotfixInterval = Convert.ToDecimal(ReadInfo("HotFixInterval"));

    if (_HotFixViewAll != "Y")
    {
        DateTime DateNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan datetimeInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays((double)_hotfixInterval);
        DateTime StartTimeGenerated = DateNow.Subtract(datetimeInterval);

        var filterScript = ScriptBlock.Create("$_.InstalledOn -gt $StartTimeGenerated");
        var whereCommand = new Command("Where-Object");
        whereCommand.Parameters.Add("FilterScript", filterScript);
        whereCommand.Parameters.Add("ArgumentList", StartTimeGenerated);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(whereCommand);
    }

    var sortCommand = new Command("Sort-Object");
    sortCommand.Parameters.Add("Property", "InstalledOn"); 
    sortCommand.Parameters.Add("Descending");
    pipeline.Commands.Add(sortCommand);
}

How can I resolve this?
Full Approach
                using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo))
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
                    {
                        // Command to execute remotely
                        var psCommand = new Command(command);
                        pipeline.Commands.Add(psCommand);

                        if(command == "get-hotfix")
                        {
                            _HotFixViewAll = ReadInfo("ViewAllHotFix");
                            _hotfixInterval = Convert.ToDecimal(ReadInfo("HotFixInterval"));

                            if (_HotFixViewAll != "Y")
                            {
                                DateTime DateNow = DateTime.Now;
                                TimeSpan datetimeInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays((double)_hotfixInterval);
                                DateTime StartTimeGenerated = DateNow.Subtract(datetimeInterval);

                                var filterScript = ScriptBlock.Create("$_.InstalledOn -gt $StartTimeGenerated");
                                var whereCommand = new Command("Where-Object");
                                whereCommand.Parameters.Add("FilterScript", filterScript);
                                whereCommand.Parameters.Add("ArgumentList", StartTimeGenerated);
                                pipeline.Commands.Add(whereCommand);
                            }

                            var sortCommand = new Command("Sort-Object");
                            sortCommand.Parameters.Add("Property", "InstalledOn"); // Sort by InstalledOn column
                            sortCommand.Parameters.Add("Descending"); // Sort in descending order
                            pipeline.Commands.Add(sortCommand);
                        }
                        else if (command == "Get-ADDomainController")
                        {
                            psCommand.Parameters.Add("Server", machinename); // Add the target parameter
                        }
                        else if(command == "Get-ADReplicationPartnerMetadata")
                        {
                            psCommand.Parameters.Add("Server", machinename); // Add the target parameter
                        }

                        // Execute the command
                        var results = pipeline.Invoke();



You can show respect for those who might help you be making the minimal effort to ensure your code samples are formatted properly, and not indented extra to the right.

There are a 2 issues with your current approach, first, ArgumentList doesn't exist as parameter of Where-Object. The second issue is more complicated, since you're using a connectionInfo: RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo), everything is serialized so trying to pass-in a script block to the remote session: ScriptBlock.Create("$_.InstalledOn -gt $StartTimeGenerated"); will fail.
This is proven by the following code, in PowerShell side:
$proc = Start-Process powershell -PassThru
$connection = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($proc.Id)
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($connection)
$rs.Open()
$pipeline = $rs.CreatePipeline()
$pipeline.Commands.Add('Get-HotFix')
$where = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command]::new('Where-Object')
$where.Parameters.Add(
    'FilterScript',
    [scriptblock]::Create('$_.InstalledOn -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-1)'))
$sort = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command]::new('Sort-Object')
$sort.Parameters.Add('Property', 'InstalledOn')
$sort.Parameters.Add('Descending')
$null = $pipeline.Commands.Add($where)
$null = $pipeline.Commands.Add($sort)
$pipeline.Invoke()
$proc.Kill()

The above fails with same issue as you're experiencing:

Cannot convert the "$_.InstalledOn -gt [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-1)" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"."

The simplest solution I can think of in this case will be to use Where-Object Comparison statement instead of Script block, with this approach you don't need to create a Script Block at all:
$proc = Start-Process powershell -PassThru
$connection = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($proc.Id)
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($connection)
$rs.Open()
$pipeline = $rs.CreatePipeline()
$pipeline.Commands.Add('Get-HotFix')
$where = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command]::new('Where-Object')
$where.Parameters.Add("Property", "InstalledOn")
$where.Parameters.Add('GT')
$where.Parameters.Add('Value', [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-1))
$sort = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command]::new('Sort-Object')
$sort.Parameters.Add('Property', 'InstalledOn')
$sort.Parameters.Add('Descending')
$null = $pipeline.Commands.Add($where)
$null = $pipeline.Commands.Add($sort)
$pipeline.Invoke()
$proc.Kill()

A notable mention, unrelated but CreatePipeline() is an old API. You should prefer PowerShell fluent API over it.
In summary this is how you could fix the issue:
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

using Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo);
runspace.Open();

using PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
// Command to execute remotely
// (don't need to create `Command` instance, a string can work)
powerShell.AddCommand(command);

if (command == "Get-Hotfix")
{
    _HotFixViewAll = ReadInfo("ViewAllHotFix");
    _hotfixInterval = Convert.ToDecimal(ReadInfo("HotFixInterval"));

    if (_HotFixViewAll != "Y")
    {
        DateTime DateNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan datetimeInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays((double)_hotfixInterval);
        DateTime StartTimeGenerated = DateNow.Subtract(datetimeInterval);

        // here you can use the approach shown in the PowerShell code
        // with the fluent API, this can be:
        powerShell
            .AddCommand("Where-Object")
            .AddParameter("Property", "InstalledOn")
            .AddParameter("GT")
            .AddParameter("Value", StartTimeGenerated);
    }

    powerShell
        .AddCommand("Sort-Object")
        .AddParameter("Property", "InstalledOn") // Sort by InstalledOn column
        .AddParameter("Descending"); // Sort in descending order
}

// then
powerShell.Invoke();


Thank you for the response. What if I am trying to run this code on a remote PC using WSManConnectionInfo?

I modified my code to use your approach. However, the results were looking at the PC on which I am running the code, not the remote PC.

It worked, I forgot to add the line powerShell.Runspace = runspace; which is why it was targeting the local PC.

No problem, I am just facing issue on the line runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set("StartTimeGenerated", StartTimeGenerated); where I am getting
System.Management.Automation.PSNotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

@NeoGenesis521 actually my bad, seems like .SessionStateProxy.PSVariable isn't available either when using a ConnectionInfo. I'll update in a few minutes

Another update, I changed the line to runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("StartTimeGenerated", StartTimeGenerated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
however, it will come back to the same error in the powershell.Invoke()
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: 'Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "$_.InstalledOn -gt $StartTimeGenerated" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".'

@NeoGenesis521 ok sorry about that, didn't consider that you were using a connectioninfo so my previous answer was incorrect. Please have a look at the update and let me know if it works now

Thank you, it works now and I didn't get the error. I would like to know the right approach when using Where-Object because I set the StartTimeGenerated to 12/11/2024 and there are records on 18/11/2024. However, the results count is always 0 (var results = pipeline.Invoke();). Why is it 0 when it should get the number of records on 18/11/2024?

I sorted it out, I was setting the date as dd/MM/yyyy when it should have been MM/dd/yyyy. Thank you for your help on this post.

Side question, with hotfix I know it can also be done with Win32_QuickFixEngineering as WMI. If I want to make it as SQL, is this the right format? SELECT * FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering where InstalledOn >= '20241112' order by InstalledOn desc or do I need to run select without filter and then filter the results by comparing the dates from the outputs?

@NeoGenesis521 YEP! the query looks fine including the WHERE (the date is in one of the accepted formats) however AFAIK WQL doesn't have an ORDER BY so that part looks incorrect and should be removed. See also this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wql?view=powershell-5.1. By the way, if you wanna use CIM you may not need PowerShell at all, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79048523/15339544 look for ManagementObjectSearcher example

Thank you for the answer and the advice. I will have a look at the links that you send me.
